# Another Easy Riley

Tags: riddle, rhyme, knowledge

I have another easy Riley riddle for the community.

> Let us seek the prefix, remove the *k* from latch.
>
> Observe the infix in it's prime, located on the map.
>
> Seek the suffix in the past, eaten by those who dwell.
>
> Together not the word you seek; the synonyms will surely tell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are

> Locate/Found

Let us seek the prefix, remove the k from latch.

> Loc from [Mark](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72493/another-easy-riley/72495#72495)!

Observe the infix in it's prime, located on the map.

> Ca for California

Seek the suffix in the past, eaten by those who dwell.

> Ate from eat.

Together not the word you seek; the synonyms will surely tell.

> Acrostic says lost so this would be lost and found :)

Comment: Okay, I totally have to do it again; so close! Yet, so far away! LOL Pay particular attention to the final line. :)

Comment: how about rot13(Frnepu)? :D

Comment: Not it either, the riddle makes an obvious relationship to it. :D

Comment: (Jryy, V abgvpr gung gur npebfgvp vf "ybfg")  :)

Comment: Well what does that mean to you? LOL

Comment: That it could be the answer? Maybe... :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83352/discussion-between-perpetualj-and-quantumtwinkie).

Comment: QuantumTwinkie has done it again! :D

Answer (score 3):

Partial answer:

Let us seek the prefix, remove the k from latch.

> lock -> loc

Observe the infix in it's prime, located on the map.

> peak(?) height? - mountain peaks are located on the map, and the meaning is similar to prime

Seek the suffix in the past, eaten by those who dwell.

> eon is a geologic time unit

Together not the word you seek; the synonyms will surely tell.

> loc...eon?

My wildest guess:

> loc height eon -> location?

Last guess for today:

> If US is in its prime, then it might be **locust**.

Comment: So close, yet so far away! :D Haha, see my pun there? LOL Still a good answer and you seriously are close; the prefix is correct but the infix and suffix are wrong.

Comment: Was pretty sure that it would be the case. XD Someday I'll solve 'em. Someday...

Comment: Suddenly your answer grew farther from the truth lol Good attempts either way!